# Add callback to angularjs service method

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way of adding a callback method to a function that calls service
in a function i am calling multiple service methods and i want to a set a callback method to that function. 
I tried this but no luck

```
$scope.MyFunction() = function()
{
    //Multiple Service calls
    $scope.callService1 = service.CallService1() //returns true on success
    $scope.callService2 = service.CallService2() //returns true on success
    $scope.callService3= service.CallService3() //returns true on success

    if($scope.callService1  && $scope.callService2 && $scope.callService3)
    {
        $scope.CallbackMethod ();
    }
}

$scope.CallbackMethod = function()
{
    alert('CallbackMethod')
}
```

I tried this one too but its not in sync as the service calls takes some time.

```
$scope.MyFunction() = function(CallbackMethod)
{
    //Refer Above Code
}
```

CallService service Method is something simple like

```
$http.post('/InstStrategy/ReadAll').then(function (response) {
    return true
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for promises https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Show us the content of CallService1 function, please

Comment: Edited the question with the service function. Thanks

Comment: Your service method doesn't return anything. So callService1 (and 2 and 3) are all `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `CallService1`, `CallService2` and `CallService3` are async methods, they should return a deferred promise. For example:

```
this.CallService1 = function() {
  // Once the result is available resolve the promise.
  return $http.post('/InstStrategy/ReadAll').then(function(response) {
    return true;
  });
}
```

Now, it's time to define your function:

```
$scope.MyFunction = function(callback) {
  var callService1 = service.CallService1(),
      callService2 = service.CallService2(),
      callService3 = service.CallService3();

  // We want to wait for all these three methods to complete.
  $q.all([callService1, callService2, callService3])
    .then(function(results)) {
          // Results is an array containing the results of each of your service calls.
          var allTrue = true;
          angular.forEach(results, function(result) {
            if (!result) allTrue = false;
          });

          // If all the service calls where true, perform our callback.
          if (allTrue) callback();
    });
};
```

Note that the allTrue check is not really necessary, since the promises are systematically resolved with true.

Comment: Can you update your first answer without using the "forgotten promise" pattern? Your answer would be read by many people so it's in their best interest to read the best practices.

Comment: I edited your answer to make it return a rejected promise in case the $http call fails. Your original answer used an antipattern, as noted by lycool. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/